# railsのモデルのリレーションについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

以下のモデルを前提に話します。

### Post

- id
- title

### User

- id
- name

`Post`に`created_user_id`と`updated_user_id`を追加したいのですが、どのようにしたらよいのでしょうか。

`user_id`を追加するなら
`raild g migration AddUserIdToPost user_id:references`とすればいいとおもうのですが、

`raild g migration AddCreatedUserIdToPost created_user_id:references`としてしまうと`CreatedUser`というモデルと結びつけることになりますよね?

`created_user_id`と`updated_user_id`両方とも`User`と結び付ける方法を教えて下さい

Answer (score 1):

マイグレーション一発で実現する方法は無さそうなので、

```
rails g migration AddCreatedUserIdToPosts created_user_id:integer
rails g migration AddUpdatedUserIdToPosts updated_user_id:integer
```

としてintegerのカラムを追加した後、モデルに書いていくことになろうかと思います。

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :created_user, :class_name => User
  belongs_to :updated_user, :class_name => User
end
```

ついでに User にも書いておくと良さそうです。

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :created_posts, :class_name => Post, :foreign_key => :created_user_id
  has_many :updated_posts, :class_name => Post, :foreign_key => :updated_user_id
end
```

Active Recordの関連付けについては、http://railsguides.jp/association_basics.html に詳しくまとまっています。